Profit from fractional share math
Let’s say I bought google at 177.02 and then it increased at 185.28. However, I bought google as a fractional share so it’s 88.51. Do I get the profit from a regular share where we do
(185.28-177.02)/177.02= 0.046661394192747 or is that reduced to half because I bought it at 88.51?

I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you asking whether you can get the same amount of money for your half a share as you would for a full share?

Yeah the profit is 4% or 8 dollars as you can subtract the values, will I get 8 dollars or half of that since I bought it at half when it was at 177

The prices quoted in the market reports are for full shares. So if you own half a share and a full share is worth $185.28, it means that your asset is worth $92.64. Given that you purchased it for $88.51, your potential gain is $4.13, which unsurprisingly is ~4.66% gain.

Yeah I figured it would be half of the gains :p thanks for the confirmation
